# create an command which sends an email to the admin Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

Hello every one i wanna create an command which sends an email to the admin containing the modification / deletion report + access in a table (use the data in the log file)  can someone help me please

for example this is my observer it log the actions in a file so how can i make a command which sends an email to the admin containing this actions from the log file ?

```
public function created(AppKey $appKey)
{
    Log::channel('obsinfo')
        ->info("id : ".$appKey->id." type : ".$appKey->type." , datetime : ".now()." operation :Creation , ip :".\Request::ip()." userAgent: ".\Request::server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'));
   return true;  
}
```

Comment: please share your code what you try and what you faced problem??

Comment: @A.ANoman look now

Comment: `Mail::to` use to send mail